# Determine the distribution of $\int_0^t (W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t) ds$, where $(W_s)_{s\geq 0}$ is a brownian motion

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have to find the distribution of $X_t:=\int_0^t (W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t) ds$ where $(W_s)_{s\geq 0}$ is a brownian motion.

I already showed the first integral $\int_0^t W_s ds$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,t^3/3)$. How should I proceed with $\int_0^t sW_tds$?

Comment: Get $W_t$ out of the integral and you see it's another centered normal distribution, then you can use Fubini to compute the covariance of these two normal distributions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main goal of the exercise is to make you realize (and use the fact) that the random variable $X$ defined as 
$$
X=\int_0^tY_s\mathrm ds,
\qquad 
Y_s=W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t,
$$ 
is a linear combination of the gaussian family $(W_s)_{0\leqslant s\leqslant t}$ and that, as such, $X$ is itself gaussian. 
Hence, to fully determine the distribution of $X$, all there is to do is to compute $E(X)$ and $\mathrm{var}(X)$.

Let me assume that you can show that $E(X)=0$ and let me turn to the computation of the variance. Note that
$$
E(X^2)
=
E\left(\int_0^t\int_0^tY_sY_u\mathrm ds\mathrm du\right)=2\int_0^t\int_0^uE(Y_sY_u)\mathrm ds\mathrm du.
$$
The computation of $E(Y_sY_u)$ for every $0\leqslant s\leqslant u\leqslant t$, then of $\mathrm{var}(X)$, should not be a problem now.

Comment: So... you do know how to prove that E(X)=0, right?

Comment: It may seem naive but I thought I could simply take the expectation inside the integral

Comment: Quite so--once you checked the hypothesis of Fubini theorem holds.

Comment: yes, true...I did this way:

$$E|N(0,s)-\frac{1}{t}N(0,t)|=E|N(0,s+s^2/t)|=\sqrt{(ts+s^2)/t}E|N(0,1)|=c \sqrt{(ts+s^2)/t}$$

$$\int_0^T E|N(0,s)-\frac{s}{t}N(0,t)|ds\leq \int_0^T c \sqrt{(ts+s^2)/t} < \infty$$

Comment: Sure your comment applies to this question? There is no $N(0,t)$ here.

Comment: $W_t$ is $N(0,t)$...

Comment: Ah OK, I understand (usually N(0,t) is used for the *distribution*, not the random variable). Then no, $W_s-(s/t)W_t$ is not $N(0,s+s^2/t)$ but yes, the computation in your comment can be used to show the hypothesis of Fubini.

Comment: I forgot the two variables are not independent...there is also the covariance term...once computed everything I obtained a 
$$N(0,\frac{s}{t}(t-s))$$
then everything should be as above. Really thx for the patience ;)

Comment: I succeded to compute also $E[X_tX_s]$ by adding$ \int_s^t\int_0^s E[Y_sY_u]dsdu$ to the previous quantity, but I'm stuck with $E[e^{\lambda X_t}|\mathcal{F_s}]$. I'm factoring the $\mathcal{F_s}$-measurable part out of the integral.

Comment: $$E[e^{\lambda\int_0^s(W_s-s/tW_t)ds+\lambda\int_s^t W_s-s/tW_t)ds}|\mathcal{F_s}]$$
$$e^{\lambda\int_0^sW_sds-\lambda s^3/2t}E[e^{-\lambda s^3/2t(W_t-W_s)+\lambda\int_s^t(W_s-(s/t)W_t)ds}|\mathcal{F_s}]$$
Now everything inside the expectation is independent of $\mathcal{F_s}$:
$$E[e^{-\lambda s^3/2t(W_t-W_s)+\lambda\int_s^t(W_s-(s/t)W_t)ds}]$$
The mean of the exponent is $0$, my only problem is with the covariance between the two (when computing the variance).
Any hint? (