# $E[e^{\lambda X_t}|\mathcal{F_s}]$, where $X_t=\int_0^t(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t )ds$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

I was trying to compute $E[e^{\lambda X_t}|\mathcal{F_s}]$, where $X_t=\int_0^t(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t) ds$, $\mathcal{F}$ is associated to $W$.
I tried the following.

1) Splitting the integral $\int_0^s$ and $\int_s^t$:
$$E[e^{\lambda[\int_0^t(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t ds)+\int_s^t (W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t ds)]}|\mathcal{F_s}]$$
2)taking out all the measurable elements
$$e^{\lambda\int_0^sW_sds}E[e^{\lambda [W_t(-s^2/2t -\frac{1}{t} (\frac{t^2-s^2}{2}) + \int_s^tW_sds]}\mathcal{F_s}]$$
3)Taking increments, I arrive here 
$$e^{\lambda\int_0^sW_sds+\lambda W_s(t/2-s)}E[e^{\lambda (W_t-W_s)(t/2-s)-\lambda\int_s^t(W_t-W_s)ds}|\mathcal{F_s}]$$
that expectation should be independent of $\mathcal{F_s}$, hence
$$E[e^{\lambda (W_t-W_s)(t/2-s)-\lambda\int_s^t(W_t-W_s)ds}]$$
the mean of the exponent is $0$, my problem is the variance, and in particular

$$E[(W_t-W_s)\int_s^t(W_t-W_s)ds]$$

ps continues from here (but I think it was off-topic there):
[Determine the distribution of $\int_0^t (W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t) ds$, where $(W_s)_{s\geq 0}$ is a brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906774/determine-the-distribution-of-int-0t-w-s-fracstw-t-ds-where-w-s)

Comment: Again you are using $s$ twice: Outside of the integral ($\mathbb{E}(\ldots \mid \mathcal{F}_s)$) and as an integration variable ($\int_0^s \ldots \, ds$). This doesn't make sense.

Comment: ...Showing the care with which previous answers are read.

Comment: I read that this is not possible, but I don't see any other way than step 1),2),3) (which make me arrive to the passage).
This because, here, I have first to make the expectation independent of $\mathcal{F_s}$.
Is there any other way (to make the expectation independent of $F_s$ I mean)?

Comment: @VittorioApicella That's simply a matter of notation. If $s$ is a fixed number, you cannot use it simultaneously as a variable of integration. E.g. $\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^s W_r \, dr \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right)$ makes sense but $\mathbb{E}\left( \int_0^s W_s \, ds \mid \mathcal{F}_s \right)$ doesn't.